# ExecJS::RuntimeError on any page including coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript, execjs

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index
```

I'm getting an error like this on every single page of my app. Everything used to work... for some reason it isn't working now when I restarted my app.

I am on Windows

I have node already installed, tried adding the following to my boot.rb to ensure it's using node

```
ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
```

I have

```
gem 'execjs'
```

but NOT rubyracer, because according to my research,

1. Node is supposed to work too
2. rubyracer can't install on windows (when I try it attempts to install libv8 which gives me errors on windows)

I'm sure it's something silly, I mean it was JUST working. I am using thin server and start with `thin start`

The error in my log is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (["ok","<Some OK looking javascript code>"])
(in <path>/global.js.coffee)
```

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require global
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: can you post the OK looking code?

Comment: You ever solve this?  Because its happening for us too...